# Datetime() returns wrong values

Tags: matlab, datetime

I am trying to plot in matlab using values for the x-axis from a *datetime array*.
Example of one value: '2016-06-03T13:37:20.315Z'
At first the values are saved into a struct array from where I try to copy them into a separate array. I do it with the following code:

```
 timestamp=[];
 for j=1:length(data)
   timestamp = getfield(data,{j},'timestamp');
   timestamp{j}=(datetime);
end
```

But when I take a look at the array it seems like all the values are one date, which is not even in the "data" struct array.
Example:

```
timestamp{1} = '14-Dec-2018 00:31:05';  
timestamp{10} = '14-Dec-2018 00:31:05';   
timestamp{19} = '14-Dec-2018 00:31:05';
```

My first thoughts were that it is probably because of the input format so I tried

```
timestamp{j}=(datetime(timestamp,'InputFormat','uuuu-MM-dd''T''HH:mmXXX','TimeZone','UTC'));
```

But I got a message: "*Error using datetime (line 635)
Unable to convert '2016-06-03T13:37:20.315Z' to datetime using the format 'uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX'.*"

Any ideas?

Comment: In your for loop you are iterating along `i`, but you are accessing the `j`th object in data. This likely explains why they are all the same date, but doesn't explain the incorrect date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are numerous errors in your code. They are summarized below.**

1. You are looping to get the data stored in a field in the given structure. Whereas you can directly get all the data stored within a particular field in a struct just using the getfield() function.
2. In the loop you are just using the **datetime** function simply to populate the timestamp variable. As a result each time when datetime is called it returns the current time, hence populating the array with the same value at each position.
3. You can not directly convert a date char array having TimeZone offset directly to datetime format. You need to remove the offsets first with strrep() command.

**Solutions to the problem**

> 1. You should use getfield function to access the timestamp char array from
>      the data struct altogether in a single line without using loops.

*-*

> 2. You should remove the offset fields(T and Z) first from the date char array and

*-*

> 3. Finally, you should convert the **edited datetime strings** back to the **datetime** type using required format to be used in plot.

**The code illustrating the procedure is given below.**

```
% suppose we have a struct named data 
% with a field known as timestamp holding the
% different datetime char arrays of particular 
% TimeZone offsets
data.timestamp = {'2016-06-03T13:37:20.315Z', '2016-07-10T17:45:20.200Z', ...
                '2016-07-09T13:37:21.305Z', '2016-11-10T01:30:20.320Z'};

% now getting the timestamp field elements in a variable using getfield()
% command
timestamp = getfield(data, 'timestamp')

% now removing each offsets chars(T and Z) from each datetime strings
edited_timestamp = strrep(timestamp, 'T', ' '); % removing T
edited_timestamp = strrep(edited_timestamp, 'Z', '') % removing Z

% finally, convert the edited_timestamp back to datetime type using the
% required format to use in plot
timestamp_datetime = datetime(edited_timestamp, 'Format', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')

% ------------------------------------------------------
% now you can do the plotting here using timestamp_datetime
% ------------------------------------------------------
% e.g., plot(timestamp_datetime, [1:4])
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing and type conversion are just a bit confusing, see my comments...

```
% Your code:
timestamp=[];                                     
for i=1:length(data)                              % Your loop variable is "i"
    % You override the entire "timestamp" array here, with element "j" not "i" of "data"
    % You also don't need to use getfield here
    timestamp = getfield(data,{j},'timestamp');  
    % You override element "j" (again, not "i") with the CURRENT datetime.
    % This line doesn't do any type conversion, "datetime" with no arguments is now!
    % Also you're using curly braces for indexing, which isn't right for a datetime array
    timestamp{j}=(datetime);
end
```

You can correct this as follows:

```
timestamp = NaT(1,length(data)); % pre-allocate the output to "not a time" array
for ii = 1:length(data)
    t = getfield( data, {ii}, 'timestamp' );
    t( t == 'T' | t == 'Z' ) = []; % remove T and Z, they will break datetime
    timestamp( ii ) = datetime( t, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS' );
end
```

Output:

```
timestamp = 
 1×2 datetime array
 03-Jun-2016 13:37:20   03-Jun-2016 13:37:21
```

(Created using your example string, and the same string with one second added).

---

That's how to correct your code, here's how I would do it:

```
timestamp = regexprep( {data.timestamp}, '[TZ]', '' );
timestamp = datetime( timestamp, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS' );
```